# Why am I not able to get BeautifulSoup to work as described?

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I am pretty new to Beautiful Soup, so I am willing to accept I am probably doing something pretty stupid, never the less, after reading through the documentation as well as following about 4 different online tutorials, I am not having the success I am expecting.  But first let me explain the use case.

The objective is to initiate a search against a holiday home website such as in this case stays with a specific set of criteria but changing the dates so that I can work out when I will get best value for a holiday. I want to store all the returned results into a database for further analysis.

But the first step is being able to capture the results. So here is my code.

```
# beautiful soup libraries
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from urllib.request import Request, urlopen
import urllib.request

# Define & request the url that we want to scrape
url = r"https://www.stayz.com.au/search/keywords:warrnambool-victoria-australia/arrival:2020-10-23/departure:2020-10-25/minBedrooms/3?petIncluded=false"
html_content = urllib.request.urlopen(url)

# Pass the html_content(the webpage) through our beautiful soup object
soup = BeautifulSoup(html_content, 'html.parser')
```

so far so good, this will return a copy of the expected page... I think!
So now I want to find my specific section of the webpage, below is a screenshot of the section I am trying to scrape.

[image]

and here is the relevant section of HTML

```html
<div class="media-flex__body">
    <h2 class="HitInfo__headline hover-text" aria-hidden="true">Merri Beach House - Opposite Beach with spectacular Views &amp; Free Wi Fi</h2>
    <span class="sr-only">Property 1: Merri Beach House - Opposite Beach with spectacular Views &amp; Free Wi Fi</span>
    <div class="HitInfo__details">
        <div class="Details__propertyType Details__label" aria-hidden="true">House</div>
        <div class="Details__bedrooms Details__label" aria-hidden="true">4 BR</div>
        <div class="Details__bathrooms Details__label" aria-hidden="true">2 BA</div>
        <div class="Details__sleeps Details__label" aria-hidden="true">Sleeps 9</div>
        <div class="Details__label" aria-hidden="true">5 m<sup>2</sup></div>
        <div class="sr-only"><span>Property TypeHouse</span><span>4Bedrooms</span><span>2Bathrooms</span><span>9Sleeps</span><span>5Square Meters</span></div>
    </div>
    <div class="GeoDistance">
        <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" class="GeoDistance__icon" width="16" height="16" viewBox="0 0 16 16">
            <g fill="none" fill-rule="evenodd" stroke="#5E6D77" stroke-linecap="round" stroke-linejoin="round" stroke-width="1.5">
                <path class="GeoDistance__iconPinPath fill-transparent stroke-currentColor" d="M3.95 9.113a5.11 5.11 0 0 1 .546-6.579l.038-.038a5.11 5.11 0 0 1 7.226 0l.037.038a5.11 5.11 0 0 1 .548 6.58L8.147 15 3.95 9.113z"></path>
                <path class="GeoDistance__iconPinHole fill-transparent stroke-currentColor" d="M9.84 6.146a1.692 1.692 0 1 1-3.387 0 1.694 1.694 0 0 1 3.387 0z"></path>
            </g>
        </svg>
        <span class="GeoDistance__text">12 min. walk to the beach</span>
    </div>
</div>
```

So from what I have read, I should be able to perform the following search, and this should give me what I need:

```
inital_search = soup.find_all('div', class_="media-flex__body")
```

however, I get no results returned.

I have also tried going further up the tree and initiating a search against `class="HitCollection"`, which should return all the results if I am understanding things correctly. This does return a result, but it looks like it's a place holder rather than the actual result.

This makes me wonder if I need to use a different method to grab search results as opposed to what I would do if I was scraping a static page.

The results from my second search attempt are below. I am not very experienced with web page design, so perhaps it's something obvious to those of you out there who are. I greatly appreciate any assistance,

```html
<div class="HitCollection HitCollection--placeholder">
    <div aria-busy="true" class="Hit media-flex media-flex--left media-flex--xs" data-wdio="hit-placeholder">
        <div class="LoadingPlaceholder thumbnail--noMargin media-flex__figure Hit__loadingThumbnail"><div class="LoadingPlaceholder__inner"></div></div>
        <div class="Hit__infoPlaceholder--mobile" data-wdio="HitPlaceholder">
            <div class="LoadingPlaceholder Hit__pricePlaceholder"><div class="LoadingPlaceholder__inner"></div></div>
            <div class="LoadingPlaceholder Hit__detailsPlaceholder"><div class="LoadingPlaceholder__inner"></div></div>
            <div class="LoadingPlaceholder Hit__reviewsPlaceholder"><div class="LoadingPlaceholder__inner"></div></div>
        </div>
        <div class="Hit__infoPlaceholder--desktop" data-wdio="HitPlaceholder">
            <div class="LoadingPlaceholder Hit__urgencyPlaceholder"><div class="LoadingPlaceholder__inner"></div></div>
            <div class="LoadingPlaceholder Hit__headlinePlaceholder"><div class="LoadingPlaceholder__inner"></div></div>
            <div class="LoadingPlaceholder Hit__detailsPlaceholder"><div class="LoadingPlaceholder__inner"></div></div>
            <div class="LoadingPlaceholder Hit__infoBarPlaceholder"><div class="LoadingPlaceholder__inner"></div></div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div aria-busy="true" class="Hit media-flex media-flex--left media-flex--xs" data-wdio="hit-placeholder">
        <div class="LoadingPlaceholder thumbnail--noMargin media-flex__figure Hit__loadingThumbnail"><div class="LoadingPlaceholder__inner"></div></div>
        <div class="Hit__infoPlaceholder--mobile" data-wdio="HitPlaceholder">
            <div class="LoadingPlaceholder Hit__pricePlaceholder"><div class="LoadingPlaceholder__inner"></div></div>
            <div class="LoadingPlaceholder Hit__detailsPlaceholder"><div class="LoadingPlaceholder__inner"></div></div>
            <div class="LoadingPlaceholder Hit__reviewsPlaceholder"><div class="LoadingPlaceholder__inner"></div></div>
        </div>
        <div class="Hit__infoPlaceholder--desktop" data-wdio="HitPlaceholder">
            <div class="LoadingPlaceholder Hit__urgencyPlaceholder"><div class="LoadingPlaceholder__inner"></div></div>
            <div class="LoadingPlaceholder Hit__headlinePlaceholder"><div class="LoadingPlaceholder__inner"></div></div>
            <div class="LoadingPlaceholder Hit__detailsPlaceholder"><div class="LoadingPlaceholder__inner"></div></div>
            <div class="LoadingPlaceholder Hit__infoBarPlaceholder"><div class="LoadingPlaceholder__inner"></div></div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div aria-busy="true" class="Hit media-flex media-flex--left media-flex--xs" data-wdio="hit-placeholder">
        <div class="LoadingPlaceholder thumbnail--noMargin media-flex__figure Hit__loadingThumbnail"><div class="LoadingPlaceholder__inner"></div></div>
        <div class="Hit__infoPlaceholder--mobile" data-wdio="HitPlaceholder">
            <div class="LoadingPlaceholder Hit__pricePlaceholder"><div class="LoadingPlaceholder__inner"></div></div>
            <div class="LoadingPlaceholder Hit__detailsPlaceholder"><div class="LoadingPlaceholder__inner"></div></div>
            <div class="LoadingPlaceholder Hit__reviewsPlaceholder"><div class="LoadingPlaceholder__inner"></div></div>
        </div>
        <div class="Hit__infoPlaceholder--desktop" data-wdio="HitPlaceholder">
            <div class="LoadingPlaceholder Hit__urgencyPlaceholder"><div class="LoadingPlaceholder__inner"></div></div>
            <div class="LoadingPlaceholder Hit__headlinePlaceholder"><div class="LoadingPlaceholder__inner"></div></div>
            <div class="LoadingPlaceholder Hit__detailsPlaceholder"><div class="LoadingPlaceholder__inner"></div></div>
            <div class="LoadingPlaceholder Hit__infoBarPlaceholder"><div class="LoadingPlaceholder__inner"></div></div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: If the website loads the results dynamically, then beautifulsoup wont work and you'll have to use something else like Selenium.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should help you:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

html = '<div class="media-flex__body"><h2 class="HitInfo__headline hover-text" aria-hidden="true">Merri Beach House - Opposite Beach with spectacular Views &amp; Free Wi Fi</h2><span class="sr-only">Property 1: Merri Beach House - Opposite Beach with spectacular Views &amp; Free Wi Fi</span><div class="HitInfo__details"><div class="Details__propertyType Details__label" aria-hidden="true">House</div><div class="Details__bedrooms Details__label" aria-hidden="true">4 BR</div><div class="Details__bathrooms Details__label" aria-hidden="true">2 BA</div><div class="Details__sleeps Details__label" aria-hidden="true">Sleeps 9</div><div class="Details__label" aria-hidden="true">5 m<sup>2</sup></div><div class="sr-only"><span>Property TypeHouse</span><span>4Bedrooms</span><span>2Bathrooms</span><span>9Sleeps</span><span>5Square Meters</span></div></div><div class="GeoDistance"><svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" class="GeoDistance__icon" width="16" height="16" viewBox="0 0 16 16"><g fill="none" fill-rule="evenodd" stroke="#5E6D77" stroke-linecap="round" stroke-linejoin="round" stroke-width="1.5"><path class="GeoDistance__iconPinPath fill-transparent stroke-currentColor" d="M3.95 9.113a5.11 5.11 0 0 1 .546-6.579l.038-.038a5.11 5.11 0 0 1 7.226 0l.037.038a5.11 5.11 0 0 1 .548 6.58L8.147 15 3.95 9.113z"></path><path class="GeoDistance__iconPinHole fill-transparent stroke-currentColor" d="M9.84 6.146a1.692 1.692 0 1 1-3.387 0 1.694 1.694 0 0 1 3.387 0z"></path></g></svg><span class="GeoDistance__text">12 min. walk to the beach</span></div></div>'

soup = BeautifulSoup(html,'html5lib')

div = soup.find('div',class_ = "media-flex__body")

print(div.h2.text)
```

Output:

```
Merri Beach House - Opposite Beach with spectacular Views & Free Wi Fi
```

If u directly wanna access the `h2` tag, then use this:

```
h2 = soup.find('h2',class_ = "HitInfo__headline hover-text")

print(h2.text)
```

Output:

```
Merri Beach House - Opposite Beach with spectacular Views & Free Wi Fi
```

Plus, another thing I recommend you to do is to use `selenium` instead of `urllib` (because the page loads dynamically) to get the html code, like this:

```
from selenium import webdriver
driver = webdriver.Chrome()
driver.get(url)
html_content = driver.page_source
```

And change your parser from `html.parser` to `lxml`. Thus, here is the final code to extract the first title in the page:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from selenium import webdriver
import time
# Define & request the url that we want to scrape
url = r"https://www.stayz.com.au/search/keywords:warrnambool-victoria-australia/arrival:2020-10-23/departure:2020-10-25/minBedrooms/3?petIncluded=false"

driver = webdriver.Chrome()
driver.get(url)
time.sleep(3)
html_content = driver.page_source
soup = BeautifulSoup(html_content,'lxml')
driver.close()

div = soup.find('div',class_ = "media-flex__body")

print(div.h2.text)
```

Output:

```
Merri Beach House - Opposite Beach with spectacular Views & Free Wi Fi
```

Comment: thanks for your help. I am now at least getting further.. it would assist me greatly for future projects like this if you can explain to me how you where able to work out that selenium or html5 would solve this issue.

Comment: Things that you should always remember:

1. Always use ```selenium``` or ```AJAX``` calls to extract the source code of websites that are loaded dynamically using ```JavaScript``` (I prefer ```selenium```)

2. The parsers are determined in a trial and error method (at least that's how I do it). If one parser does not parse the html properly, then try out another parser

Comment: Sushill, I am still testing this but so far so good, but you have provided me with a realy good start to get me headed in the right direction, thank you